# swift: check if value in array exists with a conditional

Tags: swift

**json**

```
items: {
   images: ["first", "second"]
}
```

I have a state that I am defining as `imageNum`

```
@State var imageNum = 0
```

How can I use a conditional to check to see if there is an index value?  For example, if `imageNum` is `2` given the json above, the app would crash since there is no second index.  I want to use a conditional like the below before I increment `imageNum

```
if items.images[imageNum + 1] {
    imageNum += 1
}
```

I tried the above but I am getting: `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected condition type 'Bool'`

Comment: sorry but i can't understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: Maybe you could explain why you want to do this, there might be a better/simpler solution?

Answer (score 0):

`Array` has a property called `indices` and you can check if it contains a specific `Int`

```
if items.images.indices.contains(imageNum + 1) {
    imageNum += 1
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with

```
if imageNum < items.images.count{
    imageNum += 1
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but this would crash when `imageNum` is one less than `item.images.count`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67799593/15026634) for the correction.

Answer (score -2):

@FelipeCruzV10's answer was almost correct. Here is the corrected answer.

```
if imageNum < items.images.count - 1 {
    imageNum += 1
}
```